# Completely lost: Python configure script runs with errors

Tags: python, linux, configure

I downloaded tarball of python 2.7.2 to install on Suse Linux server--it comes with 2.6 and 3.1.

Untarred it (I know--wrong lingo, sorry) to a directory.

When trying to run ./configure, which should create a valid makefile I can't get past the step one:  the script reports that it can't find a compiler on the path.

But, when I run the shell in the same directory and type "make", make runs.

I am really unfamiliar with Linux, but this just seems so basic that I can't even begin to see what's wrong.

I also downloaded what appears to be an RPM file for python 2.7.2 for SUSE Linux but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get "import" this package into Yast2 or "Install Software."  These two tools seem impenetrable and hostile to packages saved in the file system rather than accessed from specific distribution web sites.

Really, this should be just trivial but it is not.

Suse uses Gnome and Gnome seems to have its own view of what the directory structure should be for desktop end user-y kinds of files.  That is where I put my downloaded tar file.  Might I do better if I put somewhere in usr?

Sorry to be so much more clueless than most stackoverflow participants but I am just not a Linux guy.

Comment: Could you edit your post to include (1) a transcript of the output of configure, and (2) the contents of your $PATH variable (echo $PATH)?

Comment: Have you read what it tells you to read?

Comment: Do you have a C compiler, such as gcc, installed?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but "untar" is actually the correct verb ;-) Or at least it's in fairly common use for that action.

Comment: have you tried "rpm -i <packagefile>" ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you simply don't have the compiler installed. Do:

```
sudo zypper install gcc
```

If a ./configure fails, there's no point in running make.

Comment: I also installed the ActiveState community build of python but that is a weenie way of doing things.  (and I meant "pretty dumb of me..." in the prior comment)    Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Suse has a package manager called Yast. It would do your installation with no fuss.